# Material-UI Data Grid - Filtering by Date with UNIX Timestamp

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

**PROBLEM**: Custom formatted date is not filterable (though it is sortable).

[Screenshot of formatted date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdqvK.png)

The date data comes from in firebase seconds(same as a UNIX timestamp), nanoseconds format & is then translated first into a Javascript date/time format(Tue Apr 13 2021 00:27:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)), then the format in the screenshot (Apr 13, 2021).

My expectation is that the issue I'm running into is that I can't format the date this way (Apr 13, 2021) and filter - the only way to filter is to format the date MM/DD/YYYY.

Column definition:

```js
{
    flex: 1,
    field: 'created',
    headerName: 'Created',
    type: 'date',
    valueFormatter: (params: GridValueFormatterParams) => {
      // first converts to JS Date, then to locale option through date-fns
      return formatDate(params.value);
    }
  },
```

**Is there any way to make this column filterable without formatting the date as MM/DD/YYYY?**

**EDIT:** I tried formatting the date as MM/DD/YYYY & the filter still fails. See screenshots below - there should be multiple dates that match the filter.

Prior to filter: [Data Grid with 4/13 date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHYOZ.png)

With filter: [Data Grid with filter applied & no matching results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtlYW.png)

Answer (score 12):

you can read [this](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/grid-col-def/)

just add valueGetter like this:

```
{
flex: 1,
field: 'created',
headerName: 'Created',
type: 'date',
valueFormatter: (params: GridValueFormatterParams) => {
  // first converts to JS Date, then to locale option through date-fns
  return formatDate(params.value);
},
// valueGetter for filtering
valueGetter: (params: GridValueGetterParams) => {
  return formatDate(params.value);
}},
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need a [valueParser](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#value-parser) to filter by user entered formatted date, converting it back into timestamp or a date object to be read during the filter. Essentially create the inverse of your `valueFormatter`.

Edit: I'm working on a similar issue and found a solution:
I made a hidden field for the timestamp:
`{ field: 'timestamp', hide: true},`

Then my date field works as follows:

```
{ field: 'date', headerName: 'Date', width: 150,
    type: 'date',
    valueGetter: (params) => `${new Date(params.getValue(params.id, 'timestamp'))}`,
    sortComparator: (v1, v2, param1, param2) =>
      param1.api.getCellValue(param1.id, 'timestamp') -
      param2.api.getCellValue(param2.id, 'timestamp'),
    valueFormatter: (params) => { return formatDate(params.value);},
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks Ilya! This solves another MUI issue I was having after a recent release broke a full-name workaround (not using first/last name columns) I cobbled together!